# Does any French bank receive SWIFT transfers without taking any commissions?

Tags: fees, transfer, france, swift

I looked at Fortuneo and Société Générale: they both take a commissions when receiving a SWIFT transfer:

- Fortuneo [takes](https://archive.org/download/banking-fees-french-banks/Fortuneo20230817.pdf) 12 EUR: https://i.stack.imgur.com/riXvc.png
- Société Générale  [takes](https://archive.org/download/banking-fees-french-banks/SG20230817.pdf) 22 EUR: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FS0G.png

Does any French bank receive SWIFT transfers without taking any commissions?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Reddit user [knightmre77](https://www.reddit.com/user/knightmre77) [pointed me](https://redd.it/15u8d98) to Revolut, which can receive SWIFT transfers without taking any commissions:

> I have been using a Revolut bank account to receive SWIFT transfers from an Asian country without any fees. I usually select OUR so that all fees are being paid at the source bank.

It doesn't require to have to Revolut business account. One may read more information [here](https://help.revolut.com/fr-FR/help/transfers/inbound-transfers/how-to-receive-money-from-another-bank/what-account-details-should-i-use-to-transfer-money-to-my-revolut-account/guide-to-international-swift-bank-transfers-to-your-revolut-account/) on how to receive SWIFT transfers in a Revolut account.